# Youtube API Recommendation IDs do not appear to be immutable

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using the Youtube Javascript client to request a list of the recommendations for the OAuth'd user:

```
gapi.client.youtube.activities.list({
    "part": "snippet",
    "home": true,
    "maxResults": 50
}).execute(function(data) {
    // etc
});
```

This returns a load of recommendations, as expected, and the recommendations don't appear to change. However, the ID of the recommendation (`data.items[k].id`) changes (usually towards the end of the ID) each time I make the request.

When I was making a similar call for Google+, the IDs that come back are the same every time for posts etc.

So should these IDs be immutable (i.e. this is a bug in the API) or is my assumption that they are always the same invalid? The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource) says:

> The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the activity.

... which doesn't really help one way or the other.

If this is the case, how do you uniquely identify these items?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the video id, you need to specify `contentDetails` as the part.

```js
gapi.client.youtube.activities.list({
    "part": "snippet,contentDetails",
    "home": true,
    "maxResults": 50
}).execute(function(data) {
    // etc
});
```